# Add tags into XML using xpath Odoo/Openerp

Tags: xml, xpath, odoo

I want to add tags into an xml file from another Odoo/Openerpmodule.
This is the code I've got however it doesn't add anything to the file.

```
<openerp>
    <data>
        <template id="website.theme_mytheme" name="mytheme" inherit_id="website.theme">
    <xpath expr='//div[@class="row mt32" id="themes-list"]' position="inside">
                       <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="well text-center">
                <div class="image">
                    <img src="pathtomyimagefile.png"
                        class="img-responsive" alt="Default lknmTheme" />
                </div>
                <div class="options">
                    <h3>My theme</h3>
                    <p>Theme slogan</p>
                    <a class="btn btn-info" href="link_to_action">Apply</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </xpath>
</template>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

Is it even possible to achieve this with xml?

Answer (score 2):

Inside your `<template>` tag, you need an ID for your new (overriding) view, and you also need to tell Odoo which view you're trying to inherit.  Activate the Odoo developer mode by clicking on "About Odoo" and then on the link in the upper-right of the popup box.  Go to the view you wish to change, then select "Manage Views" from the debug menu.  You should then be able to determine the External ID of the view, which is what you will use in your `<template>` tag.  For example, if it was the Sales Order report, the External ID of the view would be `sale.report_salesorder_document`, and the tag in your file would look like `<template id="your_view_name_here" inherit_id="sale.report_saleorder_document">`.

Also, your `<xpath>` tag needs to match something inside the inherited view. Check out the [W3C XPath Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp) for a primer. Once you've matched something via XPath, the stuff between the tags will be inserted. You don't need the second `<template>` tag.

When done, your code should look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <template id="my_view_name" inherit_id="sale.report_saleorder_document">
            <xpath expr='//div[@class='page']' position="inside">
                <div id="my_new_div">
                    Hello, World!
                </div>
            </xpath>
        </template>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

Comment: It's from the website module. and unfortunately the website doesn't have a view.

Comment: What screen/report are you trying to modify? Also, are you working with v7 or v8?

Comment: I'm trying to edit the xml from the website module from odoo (v8).

Comment: That's pretty broad.  What _specific_ aspect of the website are you working on first?

Comment: the themes xml from the website module

Comment: As in adding a new theme, or customizing the structure output by a certain piece of the website module's templates?

Comment: Let's pretend you want to add something to the footer.  The template id is `layout_footer_copyright`.  So, to override this template, you would make your `<template>` tag look like this:  `<template id="my_footer" inherit_id="website.layout_footer_copyright">`.  Then you need to use an xpath expression to tell Qweb where to make your change.  Let's just insert another div:  
`<xpath expr="//div[@class='pull-left text-muted'" position="after">
    <div class="alert alert-warning">I like bananas!</div>
</xpath>`
This tells Qweb to insert your new div after the copyright bit.

Comment: I think this might be the solution I'm looking for ! thank you, At the moment I don't have time to try it but I'll try it as soon as I can and keep you up to date

Comment: Glad to be of help.  You can mark the answer as accepted and upvoted, so that others will know that it works!

Comment: Oops! Just noticed that the xpath expression in my above comment is missing the closing `]` just before the closing quotation mark.  Can't edit it now.

Comment: I editted my first post. with the codechange I made after your suggestion. but I can' t see my theme in the themelist